# How to colour cell in column C automatically in a colour when the sum of the values of cells next to it in column A and B is 5? (Excel-VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

In column A and B there will be numbers entered manually. column C gives out the sum automatically.

I would like to program in excel-VBA the following:

> the colour of the cells in column C changes depending on the entered
>   numbers in A and B:
>
> - when the sum of cell A and B is less than 5: red
> - when the sum of the values in A and B is at least 5 AND value in cell B is at least 2: green

I think of using offset but I don't know how or if this would be the right command.

Thank you so much in advance, I am new to excel-vba and I don't know how to program it, and it will help me a lot to dig deeper into this programming language!

[image]

Comment: Can you share the code you've tried so far? This question seems related to previous ones you asked and had answered. Is there are specific issue you're struggling with?

Comment: Have you tried using conditional formatting - just to get the logic correct?

Comment: adapt the code given in this question : https://stackoverflow.com/q/53746997/4961700

Comment: conditional formatting doesn't work for me unfortunately because there are too many conditions that overlay. moreover I wouuld like to do this without the conditional formatting.

Comment: Do you know what "conditional formatting" means? It seems to be what you describe in your question, but you then say you don't want it...

Comment: Solar Mike: The difference to this one (stackoverflow.com/q/53746997/4961700) is, that I don't know how to integrate the conditions that the sum of the cells A & B next to the cell C is relevant and the value of the left one (B). Do you know how to do this?

Comment: hope my edit in the question is now more clear

Comment: Edited my answer to meet your edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A non-VBA method:**

- Select cell `C2` (the first cell to apply formatting to).
- Select *Conditional Formatting* from the *Home ribbon*.

  - Select *New Rule*.

    - Select *Use a formula to determine which cells to format*.
    - Add the formula `=SUM($A2:$B2)<5` and change the format to red.
    - Click `OK`.
  - Select *New Rule* again.

    - Select *Use a formula to determine which cells to format*.
    - Add the formula `=AND(SUM($A2:$B2)>=5,$B2>=2)` and change the format to green.
    - Click `OK`.
- Select the *Format Painter* from the  *Home ribbon* and copy the format down, or drag the cell down to copy down.

**Using VBA:**

This code will update the font colour in column C when the values in column A:B are manually updated.  If you want the cells to update based on a formula you'll have to use the `Worksheet_Calculate` and check each value in columns `A:B`.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    'Check that a value is being changed in column A:B.
    If Not Intersect(Target, Columns(1).Resize(, 2)) Is Nothing Then
        With Target

            'Check both values are numbers.
            If IsNumeric(Cells(.Row, 1)) And IsNumeric(Cells(.Row, 2)) Then

                'Change colour based on numeric values.
                If Cells(.Row, 1) + Cells(.Row, 2) < 5 Then
                    Cells(.Row, 3).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                ElseIf Cells(.Row, 1) + Cells(.Row, 2) >= 5 And Cells(.Row, 2) >= 2 Then
                    Cells(.Row, 3).Font.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
                Else
                    Cells(.Row, 3).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                End If

            Else

                'If not numeric change font to black.
                Cells(.Row, 3).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)

            End If
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional formatting applied through VBA or manually on the worksheet's Home tab.

```
Option Explicit

Sub rgy()
    With Worksheets("sheet1")
        With .Range("C:C")
            With .FormatConditions
                .Delete
                With .Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND(COUNT($A1:$B1)=2, SUM($A1:$B1)=0)")
                    .Interior.Color = vbRed
                End With
                With .Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND(COUNT($A1:$B1)=2, SUM($A1:$B1)>=5)")
                    .Interior.Color = vbGreen
                End With
                With .Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND(COUNT($A1:$B1)=2, SUM($A1:$B1)>0, SUM($A1:$B1)<5)")
                    .Interior.Color = vbYellow
                End With
            End With
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! Is this also possible without conditional formatting?

Comment: Unfortunatley this conditional formatting doesn't work for me - do you know an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Try this macro;

```
Dim cel As Range, lRow As Long
lRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
    For Each cel In Range("C2:C" & lRow)
        If cel.Value < "5" Then cel.Interior.Color = vbRed
        If cel.Value = "5" Or cel.Offset(, -1).Value >= "2" Then cel.Interior.Color = vbGreen
    Next cel
```

You could easily use conditional formatting

Comment: is this meant to be put on the worksheets hometab? thank you!!

Comment: @emil7 It can be placed in a worksheet, but it does not have to be. If it is placed in a worksheet you can use `Worksheet_Change`, it will run the code whenever any formulas on the worksheet are recalculated; or you can use `Worksheet_Calculate` for the Range. You can look up both on Google and try to implement it.

Comment: @emil7 I don't understand why you can't use conditional formatting, it would be a lot easier for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Option Explicit

 Sub Test()

    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 1 To LastRow
            If .Range("C" & i).Value < 5 Then
                .Range("C" & i).Interior.Color = vbRed
            ElseIf .Range("C" & i).Value >= 5 And .Range("B" & i).Value >= 2 Then
                .Range("C" & i).Interior.Color = vbGreen
            End If
        Next i
    End With

 End Sub
```